# How do I use GWTP with ginjector extensions?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have a mobule file with:

```
<extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.extensions" value="test.client.gin.ClientInjectorAdditional"/>
```

My ClientInjectorAdditional is:

```
public interface ClientInjectorAdditional extends Ginjector {


    NotificationFetcher getNotificationFetcher();

}
```

Now I want to inject NotificationFetcher in my entry point class. I tried

```
public class Test implements EntryPoint {

    private static final ApplicationController controller = GWT.create(ApplicationController.class);

    @Inject
    private NotificationFetcher notificationFetcher;

    @Override

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        controller.init(;
    ...

    }
}
```

The problem is that notificationFetcher is not injected.

**How do I use GWTP with ginjector extensions?**

Edit:

When I use

```
 private final ClientInjectorAdditional injector = GWT.create(ClientInjectorAdditional.class);
```

I get the following warning:

```
  No gin modules are annotated on Ginjector interface test.client.gin.ClientInjectorAdditional, did you forget the @GinModules annotation?
```

Edit:

I tried:

@GinModules({ ClientModule.class })
public interface ClientInjectorAdditional extends Ginjector { ... }

But this gives the following error:

```
[DEBUG] [test] - Rebinding test.client.gin.ClientInjectorAdditional
    [DEBUG] [test] - Invoking generator com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator
        [ERROR] [test] - Error injecting com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider
  Path to required node:

com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.RestRequestBuilderFactory [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:99)]
 -> com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.DefaultRestRequestBuilderFactory [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:99)]
 -> com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider [@Inject constructor of com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.DefaultRestRequestBuilderFactory]

        [ERROR] [test] - Error injecting com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JacksonMapperProvider: Unable to create or inherit binding: No @Inject or default constructor found for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JacksonMapperProvider
  Path to required node:

com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.Serialization [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:103)]
 -> com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JsonSerialization [com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.gin.RestDispatchAsyncModule.configureDispatch(RestDispatchAsyncModule.java:103)]
 -> com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JacksonMapperProvider [@Inject constructor of com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JsonSerialization]

[ERROR] [test] - Deferred binding failed for 'test.client.gin.ClientInjectorAdditional'; expect subsequent failures
[ERROR] [test] - Failed to create an instance of 'test.client.test' via deferred binding 
[ERROR] [test] - Unable to load module entry point class test.client.test (see associated exception for details)
[ERROR] [test] - Failed to load module 'test' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36' at http-server.fritz.box:61196
```

Comment: Try to analyze the exception. Read what is it saying? and follow the instruction mentioned in my post. I haven't used @Inject. `No default constructor found for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.ActionMetadataProvider` and `No default constructor found for com.gwtplatform.dispatch.rest.client.serialization.JacksonMapperProvider`

Comment: Remove `<extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.extensions"...` from gwt.xml. Use `GWT.create()`

Comment: In which case do I have to use <extend-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.extensions" value="test.client.gin.ClientInjectorAdditional"/>

Comment: First try to follow the steps as mentioned in my post. Let me know if it doesn't work. I can't say until and unless I have complete code. Use `GWT.create()` in place of `@Inject`.

Comment: Are you using gwtp with a gingector being auto generated for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GWTP creates the ginjector automagically with all its presenters and views getters.
it also supports extending this ginjector for non GWTP objects.
here's how you do it:

a. define an interface, lets name it GinjectorExtensions in package some.package.client

```
package some.package.client;

public interface GinjectorExtensions {
    //your objects here
    MyConstants getMyConstants();  
    MyMessages MyMessages();
    MyRequestFactory getRequestFactory(); 
}
```

b. Edit your GWT module xml file to include the following line (which tells GWTP to add your lines of code to it's autogen Ginjector):

```
   <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.extensions"
                              value="some.package.client.GinjectorExtensions"/>
```

Then you just @Inject your objects anywhere and everything should work as expected.

EDIT: after reviewing your code, just remove the "extends Ginjector" from ClientInjectorAdditional and everything should work.

Comment: How do I access the get methods in GinjectorExtensions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code directly from [Gin Tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/google-gin/wiki/GinTutorial):

Please find out the discrepancies:

- gwt.xml

  ```
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.inject.Inject"/>
  ```
- MyWidgetClientModule.java

  ```
  import com.google.gwt.inject.client.AbstractGinModule;
  import com.google.inject.Singleton;

  public class MyWidgetClientModule extends AbstractGinModule {
      protected void configure() {
          bind(MyWidgetMainPanel.class).in(Singleton.class);
      }
  }
  ```
- MyWidgetGinjector.java

  ```
  import com.google.gwt.inject.client.GinModules;
  import com.google.gwt.inject.client.Ginjector;

  @GinModules(MyWidgetClientModule.class)
  public interface MyWidgetGinjector extends Ginjector {
      MyWidgetMainPanel getMainPanel();
  }
  ```
- MyWidgetMainPanel.java

  ```
  import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;

  public class MyWidgetMainPanel extends Button {

  }
  ```
- EntryPoint.java

  ```
  private final MyWidgetGinjector injector = GWT.create(MyWidgetGinjector.class);

  public void onModuleLoad() {

      MyWidgetMainPanel mainPanel = injector.getMainPanel();
      mainPanel.setText("Hi");
      RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution is to inject `Provider<NotificationFetcher>` in constructor and then call `provider.get()` every time you want to instantiate NotificationFetcher. No additional dependency  (like Ginjector, etc.) needs to be defined.